# Adding DevExtreme to an Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I'm using suggested command to add DevExtreme to my angular project.
`npx -p devextreme-cli devextreme add devextreme-angular`. It seems like there is a problem with node-modules/sass/embedded or with self signed certificate. I've tried the most popular solutions like setting strict SSL certificate to false and so on.
I get a following list of errors.

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\cp\Csharp\SuperHeroNG\SuperHero.UI\node_modules\sass-embedded
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\cp\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-7e00fe16.cmd
npm ERR! Downloading dart-sass-embedded release asset.
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://github.com/sass/dart-sass-embedded/releases/download/1.54.3/sass_embedded-1.54.3-windows-x64.zip failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cp\Csharp\SuperHeroNG\SuperHero.UI\node_modules\sass-embedded\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)     
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
npm ERR!   errno: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-08T12_17_54_459Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
1
```

I use:

```
Angular-cli: 14.0.2
npm: '8.16.0',
node: '16.13.1',
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe a bit late but I was able to fix it by adding the proxy configuration also in the global environment variables.
I added the following environment variables.

```
http_proxy = <your_proxy>
https_proxy = <your_proxy>
httpproxy = <your_proxy>
httpsproxy = <your_proxy>
```

Environment Variables I added:

[image]

Some programm or code that is called in the background after installing, tries to download the sass release from github. This program doesn't use / have access to the npm proxy configuration. But via environment variables we can change that.

For reference I just added all of these Environment variables via the Windows Environment variable UI that you can search for.